# Last name in bibliography, online latex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I found a bunch of threads with similar problems, but I didn't manage to solve mine, because slightly different.
I would like to have the bibliography shown as:

> Doniger, W.. Splitting the Difference. Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 1999.

Instead, I have:

> W. Doniger, Splitting the Difference. Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 1999.

my code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}
...
\printbibliography
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

Basically I only need to invert the first name and the last name without changing anything else, because it is already in alphabetical order and with the citation style that I need. I use an online version of latex, so I don't know if I can change the packages (and I don't know how to do it). Any idea?

Comment: Most of the code you have shown is standard BibTeX/`natbib`, but you also call `\printbibliography`, which is only defined by `biblatex`. This should get an error message (if you are using Overleaf, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7898/35864). You probably should drop the call to `\printbibliography` with this setup.

Comment: That said, the name format is defined by your bibliography style (`abbrvnat`), if you want to change that, you need to modify the bibliography style or change the style.

Comment: Thanks @moewe, it works even without the  \printbibliography, but I did not understand how to modify the names order. Could you please give an example or a reference link?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of deleting the `biblatex` and `citing` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows.

- Find the file `abbrvnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. If you work with an online LaTeX compiler, I suggest you obtain the file from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/.
- Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say `abbrvnat-reverse.bst`. Don't edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.
- Open the file `abbrvnat-reverse.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the file `abbrvnat-reverse.bst`, locate the function `format.names`. In my copy of this file, the `format.names` function starts on line 216.
- In this function, locate the following line:

  ```
      { s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  Change this line to

  ```
      { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```
- Save the file `abbrvnat-reverse.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located (this instruction applies if you use an online LaTeX compiler) or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, please also update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main TeX file, change

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat-reverse}
  ```
- Finally, perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mico , that was very clear and it worked perfectly! :)